# Show that if $u>v$ then $(u \mod v)\le u/2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to prove:

if $u>v$ then $(u \mod v)\le u/2$

i tried messing around with it, and tried a bunch of prime numbers.

$29 \mod 17 = 12 \le 29/2$
$31 \mod 17 = 14 \le 31/2$
$33 \mod 17 = 16 \le 33/2$
$37 \mod 19 = 18 \le 37/2$

i know that the equal sign in the above should be 'congruent to' but didnt know how to type the sign. The above is just a couple of examples that i tried, i found that if you use prime number, you can get the congruency really close to $u/2$. But i don't know how to prove that this works for all $u$ and $v$. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Use \cong to get $\cong$, use \equiv to get $\equiv$.

Answer (score 2):

$u \bmod v$ is always less than $v$, so once $u$ grows larger than $2v$ the inequality is trivially true.

Therefore all you need to consider is the case where $v< u < 2v$. In this interval it happens that $u \bmod v = u-v$. Can you prove that if $v< u < 2v$ then $u-v \le u/2 $?

Comment: u-v <= u/2 then, u <= u/2 +v, then u/2 <= v, then u <= 2v ?

Comment: @user126865: You're proving "if $u-v\le u/2$ then $u\le 2v$", but what you need to prove is "if $u\le 2v$ then $u-v\le u/2$".

Comment: k. so u <= 2v, then 0 <= 2v-u, then -2v <= -u, then -v <= -u/2, then u-v <= u/2

Comment: @user126865: Yes, so you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write $u$ as $u = kv + r$, where $r \in [0,v)$. Now we have:

$$u \equiv kv + r \equiv r \pmod v$$

So the inequality is equal to:

$$r \le \frac{kv + r}{2}$$
$$\frac r2 \le \frac {kv}2$$
$$r \le kv$$

Because $k\ge 1$ and we said that $v>r$ we get that the inequality holds. Actually it's strict inequality and you can claim that:

$$u \mod v < \frac u2$$